# How to access SQLite database on remote server? Some web service?

Tags: c#, php, .net-3.5

I have small desktop application written in .NET 3.5, that stores some data. It's small amount of data (for now its 1 table and about 1000 records total). Now Im using csv files and I have separate "databases" for each client/computer in company.

Now I need to store that data from all desktops on some online server.

I decided to use SQLite database, because its very easy to move database from one web server to another. Using normal database like MySQL or MSSQL is not an option for me - too complicated database setup/installation.

**My first idea was some XML-RPC service, but maybe there is something more simple?**

By more simple I mean no need for additional libraries (like xml-rpc.net).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're seemingly putting "easy code" ahead of "good code", or even "code that works". I just want to make it clear that—in my opinion—you're going about this the wrong way, unless there's some (very important) reason why you can't use something other than SQLite directly.

Understood? Now we can move on to your question.

Here's how I see it:

- **Use something better**. This is my preferred option. SQLite is for small stuff like settings and in-app databases. You shouldn't be using ir for anything else.
- **Export the database** by using some sort of file-level sharing (e.g. NFS, CIFS.etc). This is very dirty.
- **Expose an API to the clients** that you they interact with, abstracting any SQL or database work. This is the best solution if you're insistent on using SQLite, because when (I say when, not if) you realise the errors of you ways, you can swap SQLite out for something real and not change how the API works.

Comment: Well, this is in fact "small stuff". I don't want to force my customer, to create MySQL database. I want "just put it on your server by using FTP client" kind of database. Budget for that app is small and I have no time for database installers etc.

Comment: @Kye: I don't see any anything that answers the question!